# Where to persist data used by many controllers in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

When my `AngularJS` application runs, I need to query my API for data and I need to persist this data for the entire application lifetime. I need this persisted data to be available to all my controllers, so I will be injecting it.

My idea is to create a service that will be responsible of querying this data from my API. But I'm not sure if I will be comfortable injecting this service around - all I need is the data, not the behavior.

My question is - what is the recommended way to persist data in AngularJS and pass it around?

Comment: You could use $rootScope, which is the scope of the "ng-app" in your html main file.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant that is not a recommended practice as it gets copied again and again all the way down the scope chain

Comment: @charlietfl: i was deleted my post, i recommended a best way: using a service. But deleted ...